# Script won't execute

Tags: executable, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm having this issue on Bash for Windows, but so far as I know it works by essentially making a Ubuntu VM.

I have a program which I'm trying to run, as one does with programs.  It's called minion.  However, I get the following when I try to run it:

```
user@my_pc:~/savilerow-1.6.4-linux/bin$ ./minion
bash: ./minion: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

What the heck is going on?  Below is the information that seemed relevant about the file.  Let me know if you need more information than I gave.  Yes, I'm running this on a 64 bit machine.  Unless the Linux subsystem for Windows somehow simulates ARM?

```
user@my_pc:~/savilerow-1.6.4-linux/bin$ file minion
minion: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, stripped

user@my_pc:~/savilerow-1.6.4-linux/bin$ ls -l
total 7296
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 7470932 Feb  2  2016 minion

user@my_pc:~$ uname -a
Linux my_pc 3.4.0+ #1 PREEMPT Thu Aug 1 17:06:05 CST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Usually that means that the binary you're trying to execute is compiled for an architecture different from the one you're running on.  Add the output of `uname -a` to your question; that might be helpful.  Where did `minion` come from?

Comment: minion was provided by my professor - it's packaged as part of the Savile Row constraint solver, but when I download it independently it still doesn't work.

http://savilerow.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/releases.html

Comment: There [have](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/743) been [bugs](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1048) in WSL's ELF parsing. It's possible you're hitting one of those, or a new one. If it happens on the newest fast-ring release I suggest filing a bug.

Comment: The newest Windows release didn't change anything in the outputs.